# Hybris Solr Indexing failing

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

I have been indexing for quite a long time but now I am not able to do so. I keep on getting the following error.

> INFO  [Thread-80] (00002SB6) [SolrIndexerJob] Started indexer cronjob.
>   ERROR [Thread-80] (00002SB6) [Job] Caught throwable de/hybris/platform/solrfacetsearch/config/IndexConfig
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/hybris/platform/solrfacetsearch/config/IndexConfig
>           at ma.glasnost.orika.generated.Orika_FacetSearchConfig_FacetSearchConfig_Mapper45623933135018$4.mapAtoB(Orika_FacetSearchConfig_FacetSearchConfig_Mapper45623
>   933135018$4.java)
>           at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.mapping.strategy.UseCustomMapperStrategy.map(UseCustomMapperStrategy.java:67)
>           at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.MapperFacadeImpl.map(MapperFacadeImpl.java:735)
>           at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.MapperFacadeImpl.map(MapperFacadeImpl.java:714)
>           at ma.glasnost.orika.impl.ConfigurableMapper.map(ConfigurableMapper.java:150)
>           at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.config.impl.DefaultFacetSearchConfigService.getConfiguration(DefaultFacetSearchConfigService.java:51)
>           at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.cron.AbstractIndexerJob.getFacetSearchConfig(AbstractIndexerJob.java:70)
>           at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.cron.SolrIndexerJob.performIndexingJob(SolrIndexerJob.java:49)
>           at de.hybris.platform.multicountry.solr.indexer.cron.impl.MulticountrySolrIndexerJob.performIndexingJob(MulticountrySolrIndexerJob.java:73)
>           at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.cron.AbstractIndexerJob.perform(AbstractIndexerJob.java:40)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.jalo.ServicelayerJob.performCronJob(ServicelayerJob.java:38)
>           at de.hybris.platform.cronjob.jalo.Job.execute(Job.java:1390)
>           at de.hybris.platform.cronjob.jalo.Job.performImpl(Job.java:814)
>           at de.hybris.platform.cronjob.jalo.Job.performImpl(Job.java:732)
>           at de.hybris.platform.cronjob.jalo.Job.perform(Job.java:644)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.cronjob.impl.DefaultCronJobService.performCronJob(DefaultCronJobService.java:86)
>           at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearchbackoffice.wizards.BaseSolrIndexerWizardStep$WizardCronJobAsyncOperation.execute(BaseSolrIndexerWizardStep.java:158)
>           at com.hybris.cockpitng.engine.impl.DefaultWidgetInstanceManager$1.getResult(DefaultWidgetInstanceManager.java:206)
>           at com.hybris.cockpitng.engine.operations.ResultLongOperation.execute(ResultLongOperation.java:52)
>           at com.hybris.cockpitng.engine.operations.LongOperation.run(LongOperation.java:205)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Not sure which change is causing this issue.
Tried to setup new fresh hybris suite still the same issue. Followed hybris answers which mentioned to perform ant clean all and server startup, didn't work. Created new index and then performed indexing still the same. I am able to open solr admin but not able to index anything.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any custom Solr configuration (or impex)?

Comment: Yes. I do which is the same as previously one but somehow throws the same error mentioned above. Also I tried to create a fresh new index and try to index still the same error.

Comment: Do you have any errors on your console if you execute ant clean customize all?

Answer (score 0):

Just restarted the server. It worked for me!